# Overlap between dates

Tags: oracle

I need a help creating a SELECT stmt to validate MY_TABLE rows.

Invalid MY_TABLE configuration is if in the same table exist both a row having FLAG = 1 and one or more rows having FLAG = 0. This is an invalid configuration of MY_TABLE:

| ID | DESCRIPTION | FLAG | DATE_FROM | DATE_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First row | 1 | 2023-07-20 | NULL |
| 2 | Second row | 0 | 2023-07-21 | NULL |
| 3 | Third row | 0 | 2023-07-22 | NULL |

OK, this is easy. But valid configuration is if DATE_FROM and DATE_TO of a row having FLAG = 1 do not overlap with row(s) having FLAG = 0. So, this is a valid configuration because "First row" ends at 2023-07-25 whereas "Second row" starts at 2023-07-26, hence validity of a row having FLAG = 1 do not overlap with validity of row(s) having FLAG = 0:

| ID | DESCRIPTION | FLAG | DATE_FROM | DATE_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First row | 1 | 2023-07-20 | 2023-07-25 |
| 2 | Second row | 0 | 2023-07-26 | 2023-07-30 |
| 3 | Third row | 0 | 2023-07-27 | NULL |

There could be multiple rows having FLAG = 0 but only 1 row having FLAG = 1. If DATE_TO IS NULL that means that it is valid forever into the future. It is not a problem if DATE_FROM and DATE_TO overlap for rows having FLAG = 0 (still valid config).

Is it possible to check if MY_TABLE contains valid/invalid rows using a SELECT statement? Select should return "valid"/"invalid". Should I somehow make a self-join on DATE_FROM and DATE_TO columns?

Comment: I don't really understand your logic here, but you can look for overlapping dates pretty easily: `select * from my_table t1 where exists (select * from my_table t2 where t2.date_from < t2.date_to AND t2.date_to > t1.date_from and t2.rowid != t1.rowid)`

Comment: @PaulW Thank you very much for your help.  Can you please check your SQL once again? Should it maybe be: "...where t2.date_from < t1.date_to..."?

Comment: Yes you're right. I'll post as a answer with the corrected SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find rows with an overlapping history (start/end dated rows) dates in this manner:

```
SELECT *
  FROM mytable t1
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM mytable t2
                WHERE t2.date_from < t1.date_to
                  AND t2.date_to > t1.date_from
                  AND t2.rowid != t1.rowid)
```

Obviously if you have a histories for multiple entities (a natural key) then you'd need to include the key columns in the join.